# Compile Speed Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

I'm wondering how visual studio handles compiling a solution that is split up into sub projects, compared with a solution with just one project (with the same amount of classes for example say 200 classes).  Which would compile faster (or would they both be the same)?

Comment: Not your answer, but problem solved here by an SSD disk. After that it has become irrelevant.

Comment: Compilation in general is an O(n) problem so it doesn't matter.  What kind of overhead you might get from starting the build tools multiple times is unguessable, your question is grossly under-documented.

Comment: Just wanted to elaborate on Steve's answer. Visual Studio is very heavy on hard drive usage. Having an SSD gives an incredible performance boost.

Comment: I already have SSD's for all my devs.

Comment: I had also slow compilation issues (about 20 seconds a single project). I solved it by 1) disabling most C/C++ -> Optimization settings 2) compiling lots of .c/.cpp files into .lib export (dll); statically linking libs is much more slower. This alone zipped the compilation time into merely ~4 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's faster by compiling a solution split uf into sub projects. If you didn't change one of the other projects, it could use the already compiled dll of the unchanged sub-projects.
If all classes are located in one project, you'll have to compile the whole project everytime you build...

But more important than the building speed is in my opinion the architectural advantage of splitting your solution into sub-projects. If you have several components which could be used as standalone program or as library in another solution, it totally makes sense to split your project. This would be my approach to split a solution into sub-projects! The compilation speed is just a positive side effect of this.

check out this link for optimizing building speed: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/17/speed-up-visual-studio-builds.aspx

one more advantage you have in splitting a solution in several projects: the compiler is able to compile in parallel - even if there are some dependencies between these projects. So all in all it will be faster, i'd say.

Comment: Are you sure about this, that is what I was guessing, but don't want to be guessing.

Comment: I'm only interested in compilation speed, I already know the solution should be split up for architecture reasons, I was just checking that doing so doesn't downgrade performance.

Comment: One more improvement added: Parallel compilation of the projects!

Comment: I like the idea of the RAM disk in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer in general - it depends on many factors, including VS version. Precompiled headers might or might not be shared; whole-program optimization is really whole-link-unit optimization; linking DLLs happens at runtime and therefore doesn't count against Visual Studio build times, etc.